# Тонкий и толстый шрифт

Tags: html, css

[image: шрифт как на фото]

Как сделать шрифт тоньше и толще чем font-weight: 100/900? Сделал font-weight: 100 все равно толще чем на скрине получается

Comment: А пример кода?
Может подключен шрифт с более толстыми начертаниями?

Comment: Воспользуйтесь [этими](http://htmlbook.ru/content/svoystva-teksta) атрибутами, чтобы достичь желаемого результата.

Comment: Скрин не с моего кода. А у меня обыкновенный, стандартный Arial

Comment: Скрин вообще не кода.
Нужен проблемный код, чтобы не ванговать!

Comment: Также может быть проблема, если оборачиваешь текст в заголовок.

Comment: Не оборачиваю. Вот код: <div style="color: white; font-weight: 100; font-size: 50px">Текст</div> вот, здесь все равно получается шрифт толстее чем на скрине

Comment: Текст лучше оборачивать в <p>.
А код подключения шрифта какой?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/g05k1z7x/ все работает как должно.
Скорее всего у тебя дело в подключении шрифтов.

Comment: У меня так же работает. Но, я хочу шрифт тоньше, как на скрине.

Comment: Как который из?

Comment: Который вроде ариалом он на скрине большим шрифтом идет. <https://jsfiddle.net/m3gtkda6>  

Который самый тонкий, так и идет, но это робото. <https://jsfiddle.net/mx2gvqdr>

Answer (score 2):

Я вот специально подобрал тонкие шрифты .. на примере mini-landing в сниппете

на fiddle работает лучше : https://jsfiddle.net/0dx2tLfp/29/

```js
$(window).on("load resize", function() {
  var width = $(this).width();
  var height = $(this).height();

  $(".width").text(width);
  $(".height").text(height);
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  font-family: 'Nanum Gothic', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

header,
section,
.col {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  font-weight: 100;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

section.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 100vh;
}

section.row div {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

section.row div img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

section.row div p {
  font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.panel {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
  section.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nanum+Gothic" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">



<header>
  <h1>Hi , i am junior front end developer</h1>
</header>
<section>
  <h2>I decide every day what are the tasks</h2>
</section>
<section>
  <h2>apply ScrollMagic and Gsap</h2>
</section>
<section class="row">
  <div>
    <h2>scills</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam sed fugit cumque debitis rerum beatae distinctio sunt voluptatum, reprehenderit repellendus!
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <h2>profile</h2>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120/#ffcc00" alt="">
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus, vitae.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>portfolio</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam iure, explicabo eaque. Similique nulla modi facere cum at optio alias, ipsa quia quae animi, unde rem illo, saepe, repudiandae aliquid.</p>
  </div>
</section>

<div class="panel">
  <span class="width"></span>
  <span class="height"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: <div style="font-size: 33px; font-family:cambria, sans-serif, georgia">Текст</div> Сделал во вот таким образом, но шрифт не изменился, почему?

Comment: @Holter, возможно в самом шрифте есть только обычный стиль, ведь так?

Comment: @Holter шрифты подбирать надо - вообще типографика это целое искуство

Answer (score 0):

Вы в правильном направлении. Нужно подобрать шрифты, которые имеют нужное начертание. Но регулировать через font-weight можно только те, в которых заложено нужная «жирность». Тогда браузер сможет корректно его отобразить.

Например в Roboto есть Black900. В Open Sans есть ExtraBold800. А скажем у PT Sans есть только Bold700, то есть с ним просто не получится установить большую «жирность». С тонкими шрифтами ситуация аналогична.

Comment: Как установить шрифт на сайт? У меня он не меняется.

Comment: В гугл-фонтс https://fonts.google.com/ подбираете шрифт, после будет предложен код для вставки.

Comment: Вставил - ничего не происходит. Можете помочь?

Answer (score 0):

Сам, когда верстал с готового сайта сравнивая по скриншотам, и точно зная, что используется одна и та же шрифтовая гарнитура, столкнулся с тем, что в случае указания css свойства:

```
font-smooth: antialiased;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

Шрифт начинает выглядеть ещё тоньше, чем при `font-weight: 100;`